# Android Account manager remove option menu in settings

Tags: java, android, account, accountmanager, android-settings

I am trying to utilize Android's Account Manager to store user's app credentials. Although I am not saving the user's password , and i have added the account in settings that is working fine but i want to **remove the option menus like
Sync now and
Remove account option from settings**  like below in the screen shot 
I have added account using this code

```
 AccountManager am = (AccountManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        final Account account = new Account(MyAccountManager.ACCOUNT, MyAccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        am.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);
        am.setAuthToken(account, MyAccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, "123");
        am.setUserData(account, MyAccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, "lock");
```

[image]

Comment: and is it possible to hide these option menus from settings for my app ? if we can not remove them

Answer (score 0):

Remove-account function is part of account manager framework maintained by the system. There is no option to hide remove-account function as there needs to be a way for users to remove account from account manager.